# How can I use the API to query for institutions with student bodies greater than 1000?

Tags: collegescorecard

I tried

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?latest.student.size__gt=1000&api_key={API_KEY}
```

but it returns schools with *exactly* 1000 students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the correct API call is

```
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?latest.student.size__range=1000..&sort=student.size:desc&per_page=100&page=0&api_key={API_KEY}
```

EDIT: Start with page=0, not page=1, to avoid missing 1st page of results!